UV Python Packing: How to set environment variables in virtual envrionments
How do I set environment variables in virtual environment creating by UV? I try setting it in .venv/scripts/activate_this.py and it doesn't work.

you need to show what did you try , we will not know what you tried and why it did not work. as we dont see what you tried in detail we wont be able to help you.

How are you trying to set the environment variables? What did you use exactly? You can also try it using python-dotenv.

You can tell the uv run command to load environment variables from a file, either by using the --env-file option:
uv run --env-file=.env myscript.py

Or by setting the UV_ENV_FILE environment variable:
export UV_ENV_FILE=.env
uv run myscript.py

You will find more details in the documentation.

Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.
